# Dúvida a respeito do VSCode

Tags: ide

Olá,

já utilizo algumas ide's como o Intellij e o visual studio community,e nessas ide's quando eu utilizo o tab, ele alterna a posição. 
Exemplo:

System.out.println("Olá *Se eu apertar tab aqui, ele vai para fora da regra*");E vem para cá.

Nao sei se fui claro, mas queria saber se existe esse atalho no VSCode e se sim, como é o nome dessa função, pq nao estou conseguindo encontrar.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você está querendo alternar entre abas? Sim, tente a combinação: ctrl+tab

Comment: "ele alterna a posição" - como assim ? pode elaborar um pouco ?

Comment: Cara no VS Code o tab por padrão serve para identar o código, ou par dar autocomplite em alguma palavra. Em 90% das ide o tab só serve para isso, não deu para entender o que vc precisa

Comment: Você pode instalar os comandos do Intellij PhpStorm, se quiser, caso esteja mais acostumado, no VSCode...

Comment: Se estou pensando no que vc está querendo fazer, no meu caso, eu uso um macbook Air, eu clico no `fn` e ele anda entre os elementos da maneira que vc fala...

Comment: Atualmente eu uso o Ctrl+seta pra direita pra sair de uma instrução, sendo que no intellij eu apenas uso o tab. Mas amanhã cedo vou testar o fn no windows